# email activation for registration form

Tags: php, mysql, database, conditional-statements

i have registration form and i want user must be activated their email once user activated their then user can login in the their account else user can't be login?

**Problem**

The problem is that the users can login without email activation?

**Code**

```
$email2=$_POST['email'];
$querycheck=mysql_query("select activation from students 
                         where semail='$email2'") or die ("Query Activated Problem");
$rowcheck=mysql_fetch_array($querycheck);
$act=$rowcheck['activation'];

if($act=='activated')
  {

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $password= stripslashes($password);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $querymysql=mysql_query("select * from students where semail='$email'
                             and spassword='$password'  ") or die ("query problem");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($querymysql);


    if($row)
      {

        session_register("email");
        session_register("password"); 

        header('Location:index.php');   
      }
    else {
      $message="Please Check Your Login Details";   
      header('Location:login.php?login_error='.$message.'');    
    }

  }
else if($act=='')
  {
    $actmsg="Your Email Is Not Activated Yet";  
    header('Location:login.php?actmsg='.$actmsg.'');        
  }
```

Comment: and the quesstion would be?

Comment: problem is that user can login without email activation?

Comment: Maybe because you assign `$_SESSION['semail']` outside the `if($row)` check?

Comment: @Barmar i already check it without `$_SESSION['semail']` but still not working

Comment: `if($act=='')` should be an `else` statement... As for why it isn't working, where are you getting `$email` from in your first query `$querycheck`?

Comment: Your first query uses the variable `$email` before it's set inside the `if ($act == 'activated')`.

Comment: @Steven i'm getting email as `session` from registration form

Comment: But _(in the code shown)_ you only set that **after** the query has run as it stands your query for `$querycheck` is `select activation from students where semail=''`

Comment: Okay, I checked your edit... Firstly, `else if($act==''){/*The rest of the code*/}` should just be `else{/*The rest of the code*/}` sorry if I wasn't clear! Back to the question, add the line `echo mysql_num_rows($querycheck);` after `$querycheck` and report back the output... If it's not `1` then the problem is that you have duplicate email addresses...

Comment: please verify the caps in "activated" in the database. I had some problems with caps while using the == operator.

Comment: @AcelasiEu thank you so much i have already completed my script

Comment: So that was the problem? Please post it so others can see! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

**session_register** : This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Use **$_SESSION** directly to set variables.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field tinyint field called activated.  Then change your select to 
    select * from students where semail='$email'
    and spassword='$password'  "
    and activated=1

You activate link should set activated to 1 for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `activation` field in the `students` table. Then, lets convert your code from ***MySQL*** to ***MySQLi***. ***MySQL*** is already deprecated.

```
/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION FIRST */

<?php

$connection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","DatabaseName");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$email2=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']); /* LETS USE REAL ESCAPE STRING TO PREVENT A BIT OF SQL INJECTION */
$querycheck=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT activation FROM students 
                         WHERE semail='$email2'");
while($rowcheck=mysqli_fetch_array($querycheck)){
$act=$rowcheck['activation'];
}

if($act=='activated')
{    
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $password= stripslashes($password);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);

    $querymysql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE semail='$email'
                             and spassword='$password'");
    $row=mysqli_num_rows($querymysql); /* I CHANGED THIS PART OF YOUR CODE */

    if($row!=0) /* SO THIS CONDITION ALSO CHANGES */
      {    
        session_register("email");
        session_register("password"); 

        header('Location:index.php');   
      }

    else {
      $message="Please Check Your Login Details";   
      header('Location:login.php?login_error='.$message.'');    
    }

}

else if($act=='')
  {
    $actmsg="Your Email Is Not Activated Yet";  
    header('Location:login.php?actmsg='.$actmsg.'');        
  }

?>
```